# "Than" vs "Then" when answering question; e.g., "Then yes."

Tags: slang

In a common exchange, one might give one answer, and then change their response on new information.

For example,

A: Want to see movie X tonight?

B: Yes.

A: It starts at 11pm.

B: Then no.

.

Is the above usage of "Then no" proper or should it instead be "Than no"? Obviously, there are other grammatical usages possible, but this question is specifically asking whether "than" or "then" is proper in an exchange like the above.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked each of these words up in a dictionary? They mean different things.

Comment: @Davo I have, but their separate definitions do not clearly suggest to me an answer to this common phrase.

Comment: Then = "in that case". Than = "in comparison to". Which of the two fits grammatically?

Comment: You'd only use "than" if you were being wishy-washy and said "More yes than no".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now, I think you're mixing two different things with varied meanings over here.

> ***Than***
>
> > 1. *Used in introducing the second element in comparisons*
> > 2. *Used in introducing an exception or contrast*
>
> ***Then***
>
> > 1. *At the time in question*
> > 2. *After or next to to something*
> > 3. *In that case; therefore*

References: 
[1] https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/than

 [2] https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/then

Comment: Right. _Than_ is a special-use word; it only occurs in special constructions like the comparative (_holier than thou_). _Then_, however, is a part of the grammatical paradigms; it's a time-word related to the time-word _when_ the same way the place-word _there_ is related to the place-words _where_ and _here_.